# For loop counter in dot operator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm working in the Android ADT plugin for Eclipse.

What I try to do is this:
I have some drawables named from 0 to 150 and i want to get them into an array to use them.
As far as I know, to be usable, they have to be assigned with 
`"R.drawable.FilenameWithoutExtension"`.
To make the array creation easy and fast I want to use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
    imagesArray[i] = R.drawable.i;
}
```

But for now I get an error for that `"R.drawable.i"` because there is no file `"i"`.

Is there a way to use the numeric value of `"i"` instead of the letter for the assignement `"R.drawble."`?

Comment: Array is of type String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a resource identifer from its name using the getIdentifier() method:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 150; i++)
    imagesArray[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(i), "drawable", "your.package.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The file names must start with a letter because at build time the file names are converted to java identifiers.

After you do that you can use reflection access each of the members of R.drawable.

Comment: Good to know that! But I've never heard about that reflection access, will google that

Comment: There are lots of tutorials online, but before you read them, I think NigelK has a better solution to your problem.